# Xcode Project Setting for CGEventTap?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, cgeventtap

A while ago, I created a extremely simple Xcode project to test CGEventTap, and it works perfectly fine when I run from Xcode. The code is at the bottom.

However, if I create a new project on Xcode, paste the exactly the same code below, and run from Xcode, I get "Failed to create event tap".

Is there a project setting that I need to change in order to get CGEventTap working? I even tried to copy and paste info.plist from the old testing project to the new one.

I'm very puzzled. Thank you for your help!

```
// ViewController.swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        func myCGEventCallback(proxy : CGEventTapProxy, type : CGEventType, event : CGEvent, refcon : UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
            if type == .keyDown || type == .keyUp || type == .flagsChanged {
                let keyCode = event.getIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode)
                print(keyCode)
            }
            return Unmanaged.passRetained(event)
        }

        let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.flagsChanged.rawValue)
        guard let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: .cgSessionEventTap, place: .headInsertEventTap, options: .defaultTap, eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask), callback: myCGEventCallback, userInfo: nil) else {
            debugPrint("Failed to create event tap")
            exit(1)
        }
        let runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0)
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, CFRunLoopMode.commonModes)
        CGEvent.tapEnable(tap: eventTap, enable: true)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}

// AppDelegate.swift
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to uncheck Sandbox from capabilities.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472903/macos-app-handling-key-combinations-bound-to-global-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646681/cocoa-capture-mouse-just-like-screencapture-utility