# How can I implement the native macOS screenshot mouse behavior?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, screenshot, appkit

I'm implementing a screenshotting app that captures a portion of the screen. I'm currently:

1. listening for a keyboard shortcut
2. drawing a transparent view on top of the entire screen
3. having the user click and drag to select an area inside of that view
4. screenshotting the coordinates inside of that bounding area.

Here's an example of what it looks like (the transparent view is tinted blue):

[image]

This works, but it causes the mouse to stop focusing on whatever it was previously focusing on. In other words, if I'm hovering over a tooltip and I hit the screenshot shortcut, the tooltip vanishes before I have a chance to screenshot it.

It looks like macOS's own screenshot command does not have this problem. If I hover over a date in StackOverflow in order to see the time tooltip, I can press Cmd+Shift+4 and screenshot it pretty easily:

[image]

If I try and do the same thing with my own code, the tooltip vanishes after I render my transparent view, even if I haven't moved my mouse.

Is Apple doing something specific to maintain the focus state of the mouse that I could be doing? Alternatively, should I somehow take advantage of Apple's own screenshotting flow myself inside of this app? If it helps, I'm currently using [`CGWindowListCreateImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454852-cgwindowlistcreateimage) to actually take the screenshot.

Comment: One thing that seems like a potential solution is to create a new cursor and use that to take screenshots, leaving the original one alone. It seems like I could maybe even hide the original cursor?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor